# Get ID of front page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In the Wordpress admin settings>reading you can configure the 'frontpage displays as' as being a static page for the front page. Now I would like to retrieve the ID of the selected static page which is set to display as front page. I've tried Googling but to not much avail, thus I was wondering if there is a native function to retrieve this ID. (I don't feel like programming a workaround if there is a native direct function for this).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The ID of the page used as static page is stored in the `wp_options` WP table, as `option_name`=`page_on_front` and `option_value`=ID of the page.
So if you want to retrieve this value, just use `get_option('page_on_front')`.

As an example:

```
$front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the solution where you select a page as placeholder for the blog archive.

You can do the same, but then query for 'page_for_posts' instead of 'page_on_front'. So:

```
$pageID = get_option('page_for_posts');
```

does the trick for that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

Get the page by Title first

```
$Page = get_page_by_title( 'test' );
```

Then, get the ID like this

```
echo $Page->ID . "<br /><br />";
```

Comment: Utilizing get_page_by_title was one of the workarounds I came up with, the answer of barakadam is exactly what I'm looking for though.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to see the page_id of the static page is to change the static page to another page and then go to Pages and click on the old page. The page_id is displayed in the Permalink above the edit area.  After you see the page_id you can change the static page to the old one. The Permalink for the static page does not show the page_id but for all other pages it does.